# Multiple requests conflict time to read or copy a file

Tags: php, copy, file-exists

**Details:**

- PHP Version: 5.3.0
- Apache 2.2.37
- Windows XP SP3

I am creating a system backup error (`php error` and `custom error`) in **TXT**, not user data but the dynamically generated page.
If you have already generated the **LOG** other user does not need to generate as ever existed.

I simulated 10 concurrent connections/requests and sometimes this error occurs:
**No such file**

Code:

```
<?php
$p = 'errs/'.$arqErr;
$o = 'temp/'.$arqErr;
if(file_exists($o) && is_readable($o) && is_writable($o)){
    if(!copy($o,$p)){
        echo 'Error copy "',$p,'" to "',$o,'"';
    }
    if(file_exists($o) && is_readable($o) && is_writable($o)){
        unlink($o);
    }
}
?>
```

sometimes the error occurs:
`Warning: Unable to open 'temp/6039dd66559c9431004109202d279557.php' for reading: No such file or directory`

and sometimes the error occurs:
`Warning: Unlink failed (No such file or directory)`

Is it a bug of PHP_5.3.0?

Note: In Windows Seven with PHP5.3.4 this failure does not occur.

Comment: sounds like a race condition. if multiple users are hitting the same address then you'll have multiple copies of the php script creating/updating/deleting those files.

Comment: Each address has only one LOG.
When multiple users generate the same LOG these errors happen. I'm using `is_readable` and `is_writable`, but the errors persist.

Comment: ip address != user. consider how many millions of cellphones can 'hide' behind a single IP address of their provider's nat gateway.

Comment: @ MarcB what that has to do? My problem is on multiple accesses, regardless of origin. I would be grateful if you explain what you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be having multiple concurrent users trying to access the same files, it doesn't seem to be a PHP related problem.

Try to think of a different logging scheme, maybe using the [`error_log()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) function you can have PHP manage concurrency access issues for you.

```
<?php
error_log('Log message', 3, "md5(address of the page).LOG.txt");
?>
```

Comment: With the `error_log` function you can write anything to the file sepcified by the third parameter. Have you tried using it?

Comment: I thought about using this function yes, but preferred to follow his first tip, "is not a bug in PHP", I created a simple script like copy / rename and fwrite and functioned normally. I'll try to recreate my system LOG why should a fault elsewhere. thank you very much